# using .click and .fadeTo on jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to layer a set of 3 pictures so that they are all on top of each other. When I "mouseenter" I want the top photo to fade out, and then when I "mouseleave" I want it to reappear. I got that function to work. then I want to be able to click after I "mouseenter" and make the second photo disappear so that I can see the third photo. After that I want all of the photos to reappear and have the function continue to work no matter how many times I mouseenter, mouseleave, and click. I have gotten it to work so that the top photo disappears and reappears and then when I click I see the third photo, but when I mouseleave, I see the first photo and nothing happens when I mouseenter again. Could someone please help me figure out how to complete the task I want to do?
So far I have this as my HTML:

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>this is a title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="programs.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="10_10.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="colosseum">
        <img class="colosseum" src="http://library.thinkquest.org/CR0210200/ancient_rome/colosseum3.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="colosseumRest">
        <img class="colosseumRest" src="http://www.robinurton.com/history/ancient/rome/ColoAbove.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="colosseumNow">
        <img class="colosseumNow" src="http://hbarbosahistorybuff.edublogs.org/files/2010/11/colosseum2-1lgbsp7.jpg"/>
    </div>

</body>
```

And this as my CSS:

```
    .colosseumNow{
    min-width:400px;
    min-height:400px;
    max-width:400px;
    max-height:400px;
    margin-top:-300px;
    }
    .colosseumRest{
    min-width:400px;
    min-height:400px;
    max-width:400px;
    max-height:400px;
    margin-top:-200px;
    }
    .colosseum{
    min-width:400px;
    min-height:400px;
    max-width:400px;
    max-height:400px;
    postition:absolute;
    }
```

And this as my javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('.colosseumNow').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo('slow',0);
});
$('.colosseumNow').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo('slow',1);
});
$('.colosseumNow').click(function(){
    $('.colosseumRest').fadeTo('slow',0);
});

    });
```

Comment: Nevermind, after trying several different things I found out I could do it by doing:
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.colosseumNow').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).fadeTo('slow',0);
 });
 $('.colosseumNow').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).fadeTo('slow',1);
 });
 $('.colosseumNow').click(function(){
  $('.colosseumRest').fadeTo('slow',0);
 });
 $('.colosseumNow').mouseleave(function(){
  $('.colosseumRest').fadeTo('slow',1);
 });

});

Answer (score 0):

The easy way I can think of is make a parent div then use siblings to fade in or out all the childrens using

$(siblings).fadeTo('slow',1)

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/